# Nesting UINavigationController pushViewController twice causing pop animation problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a strange issue where if I push two (different) view controllers onto the navigation controller stack the first pop will animate correctly and the second one seems to flip the layers that needs animating. This results in an ugly transition between view controllers.

Code to reproduce is here: https://github.com/travisjo/PopViewControllerBugDemo

I'm on iOS 9.2 but it's also broken in 8.1, the oldest simulator I have.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How to write a question -> http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines from your view controllers:

```
    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

The view controller's view position and constraints are set by the parent view controller (the navigation controller, in this case). You're not supposed to touch them. Apparently they're set using a position and autoresizing, and disabling the derived constraints just breaks their layout.